# How to open up this single lever American Standard shower knob

Tags: shower

One of our showers has this American Standard single lever mixer. Lately, even with the handle turned all the way to 'hot', the water is moderately warm at best. The other faucets in this bathroom and everywhere else in the house emit sufficiently hot water, so I suspect this particular cartridge may need replacement, or maybe the temperature limit needs to be looked at.

The problem is - I don't know how to go about opening the knob. The two visible screws are obviously holding the wall-plate, but there has to be a simple (?) trick to remove the handle/knob first. Hopefully someone can recognize the model from these pictures and point me in the right direction.

[image: Picture of shower knob]
[image: Another picture of shower knob]

Comment: Is the small knob simply a cap that can pried off which would possibly give access to a screw underneath it to aid in removing the rest..?

Comment: That small knob controls the temperature and is actually spring loaded. One needs to pull it out and then turn it to move it further past the middle of the range (presumably to make sure one actually wants "really hot" water). I could, of course, be mistaken, but I have tried to tug at it and it doesn't feel like a simple cap. Hopefully someone recognizes the exact model and can chime in with confirmation.

Comment: I would look on the shaft under the pointer there is probably a set screw or grub screw holding this handle in place if not there the cap labeled tempature will probably be removable and a screw under that would release the handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image][image][image]

The front pops off, I hope this helps anyone who is looking for an answer to this!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Great answer: keep 'em coming!

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted to know at the time I asked the question (no longer have that home, but I'm sure it will help someone else).

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the spot indicated by the arrow to see if there is a set screw there. If so loosen that and the smaller first handle should come off.

[image]

Once that is removed it is likely that how to remove the other larger knob will become obvious.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no screws anywhere around either the small knob or even the bigger one. There must be some other trick to it.